# how can i get value from another CRUD in my json

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-5.8

i have json return values from order crud how can i make it return also value from User Crud by user ID

this is my code now

```
public function vendorindex(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(isset($user->id)){
            $order = Order::where('vendor_id', $user->id)->get();
        }else{
            $order = null;
        }
        return response()->json($order);

    }
```

i tried to do this but not work with me to replace another value with the value that i want

```
 public function vendorindex(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(isset($user->id)){
            $order = Order::where('vendor_id', $user->id)->get();

            foreach($order as $orders){
                $mobile  = User::where($user->mobile);
                $created_at = Order::where($orders->created_at);
                $phonenumber = array(
                    'mobile'  => $mobile, 
                    'created_at' => $created_at
                );

                $orders->created_at = $phonenumber;
            }
        }else{
            $order = null;
        }
        return response()->json($order);

    }
```

Comment: If I understood.. Do you want to sent aditional Orders into json response? or do you want to change UserId before sent json response?

Comment: Sorry but is a bit unclear to me what you wanna do and what is the error, I understood the first function but not the second one

Comment: I need to pass mobile field for the user from User CRUD to order CRUD ( in order CRUD there is user_id i want to get his mobile and show it in returned Order json )